# Can an HTTP response omit the Reason-Phrase?

Tags: http

A normal HTTP response looks like:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
```

Is it OK to omit what the [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html) calls the *Reason-Phrase*? Something like:

```
HTTP/1.0 200
```

The RFC says:

```
Status-Line = HTTP-Version SP Status-Code SP Reason-Phrase CRLF
Reason-Phrase  = *<TEXT, excluding CR, LF>
```

I understand this as:

- An empty string is OK for the Reason-Phrase
- But there should be a space after the Status-Code anyway

So the following would be valid:

```
HTTP-Version SP Status-Code SP CRLF
```

Do I understand the RFC correctly?

Comment: Why omit?  If you're looking for over-the-write byte savings, just use [SPDY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY).

Comment: @josh Building a library allowing the user to set the response code. If the user sets an exotic response code, I would have to choose between leaving the string empty, setting some king of `UNKNOWN` Reason-Phrase, or forcing the user to set the Reason Phrase as well.

Comment: FWIW, Node's base HTTP library (and thus most things built on it, like Express) [defaults to sending the string `unknown` as the Reason Phrase](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.12/lib/http.js#L1119) when the author sets an exotic status code and does not supply a reason string.

Comment: @Benjamin: FWIW, there's a fourth option, if the reason phrase for a custom status code isn't set, then use the reason phrase for the status code class (1xx Continue, 2xx OK, 3xx Redirect, 4xx Bad Request, 5xx Server Unavailable).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks that way, if you read the `*` as 'zero or more characters', like in regular expressions.

It seems to have a slightly different meaning if you read the [Notational Convention](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html#sec2) of the RFC:

> `*rule`
>
> `The character "*" preceding an element indicates repetition. The full form is "<n>*<m>element" indicating at least <n> and at most <m>
>   occurrences of element. Default values are 0 and infinity so that
>   "*(element)" allows any number, including zero; "1*element" requires
>   at least one; and "1*2element" allows one or two.`

So although it's not regex, the meaning is essentially the same. The asterix, not having a trailing number in this case, means that there can be "0 or more" "texts". Odd way to put it, but it seems you're right.

Strictly speaking, the space *is* mandatory, although I'd think a separator might be omitted if there's nothing to separate. It might kill clients that have a strict implementation, though, if they just split this string on the spaces and try to read the element in which the description should be. But then again, those clients should have used some defensive programming to catch that situation. ;)

The RFC *does* say that it can be any text, as long as it is a human readable description of the problem. This text is important, because the client may not understand the exact meaning of the status code, so it may need to display the text to the user. So even though you can omit it, I personally wouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

The Reason-Phrase is indeed optional. In fact, [HTTP/2 even dropped it entirely](http://evertpot.com/http-2-finalized/):

> [HTTP/2 does not define a way to carry the version or reason phrase that is included in an HTTP/1.1 status line.](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#rfc.section.8.1.2.4)