# Api token validation error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

What kind or error should I return in case of invalid token on a JSON API

```
    // GET api/Job
    public IEnumerable<Job_Hdr> GetJob_Hdr()
    {
        if (Validation.isValid(Request.Headers.GetValues("Token").Single()) == true)
            throw new Exception("Invalid token");
        ...
    }
```

Comment: 401 Unauthorized. By the way in your code above you throw exception when token is _valid_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31206850/5750143

You should be throwing a `HttpResponseException` from your API method, not `HttpException`:

```
throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
```

Or, if you want to supply a custom message:

```
var msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) { ReasonPhrase = "Oops!!!" };
throw new HttpResponseException(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Evk as suggested in comments, error returned should be `HTTP 401` `Unauthorized`.

In WebAPI I suggest to make return type of your function to be `HttpResponseMessage` and you can throw error like:

```
return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "String error Message");
```

So final code can be like:

```
    // GET api/Job
    public HttpResponseMessage GetJob_Hdr()
    {
        if (Validation.isValid(Request.Headers.GetValues("Token").Single()) == true)
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "String Message");
        ...
        IEnumerable<Job_Hdr> JobModelCollection=GetYourData();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, JobModelCollection);
    }
```

If you want to change API route you can also do it by decorating API method  with attribute `[Route("api/Job/GetJob_Hdr")]`. By this you can call method as `api/Job/GetJob_Hdr` & also can define multiple get method in same API using Routes.