# Return Unauthorized result with postsharp OnMethodBoundaryAspect

Tags: asp.net-web-api, postsharp

I have some api actions, that I include an aspect with OnMethodBoundaryAspect, 
I do the validation of the token that was send in request, like this.

```
[Serializable]
[MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Method, TargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Instance)]
public class TokenCallHandler : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Methodo responsável por validar o token enviado pelo usuário
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        ApiController apiController = (ApiController)args.Instance;
        var context = apiController.ControllerContext;
        HttpRequestHeaders headers = context.Request.Headers;
        bool validToken = false;
        if (headers.Contains("X-Authorization"))
        {
            var authorization = headers.GetValues("X-Authorization");
            var token = authorization.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
            if (token == null)
                token = "invalid";

            validToken = TokenUtil.ValidateToken(token);

        }

        if (!validToken)
            args.ReturnValue = new UnauthorizedAccessException();



    }

}
```

But it keeps going to execute the method in the api, I just want to return 401 exception.

If I do throw new UnauthorizedException it returns with 500 (internal server error) with unauthorized inside it, but I need the 401.

How can I capture in wep.api action the aspect returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned at [ASP.NET Web API : Correct way to return a 401/unauthorised response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205599/asp-net-web-api-correct-way-to-return-a-401-unauthorised-response),

> You should be throwing a `HttpResponseException` from your API method

By setting the `args.ReturnValue`, you are changing the return value of the method enhanced by your aspect, but you are supposed to throw an exception instead.

So the last line should be

> `throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);`
>
> Or, if you want to supply a custom message:
>
> `var msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) { ReasonPhrase = "Oops!!!" };
>   throw new HttpResponseException(msg);`

You might also consider using `MethodInterceptionAspect` (http://doc.postsharp.net/method-interception) as you are not wrapping the method execution, but you are intercepting it.