# Returning error message from .NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .NET Core Web API controller to handle a POST request which takes a JSON ApiUser object and also returns an ApiUser object

```
[HttpPost]
public ApiUser Post([FromBody] ApiUser model) {
    return new ApiUser();
}
```

Let's say I want to return an error message to the client: **"Email already exists."**  **I don't know how best to do it in a simple manner.**

I could add an "ErrorMsg" property to ApiUser (and every other class that I return through the API), but not sure if this is the correct way.

"Pre-Core", I'd throw a HttpResponseException, which is not supported in Core.  This was nice because it would create a simple JSON with "Message" which I could then grab.  (Goofy: I'd use status 202 Accepted as a flag to my client that we had a "known error".)

```
throw new HttpResponseException(request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, msg));
```

(I think I'd prefer to deal with this inside the controller, instead of "filters" or "middleware". One concern with the latter two is that if I add razor pages, I assume I'd need to know if error came from api calls or from UI web calls.)

UPDATE #1

Seems I can do the following (return **ActionResult< T>**) to simulate what I did before with HttpResponseException.  Still not sure if doing something like this or returning status 200 with adding ErrorMsg to ApiUser would be better.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<ApiUser>> Post([FromBody] ApiUser model) {
    ...
    if (emailExists) return StatusCode(400, "Email already exists.");
    else return user;
}
```

Comment: Similar/same questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41464540/returning-a-404-from-an-explicitly-typed-asp-net-core-api-controller-not-iactio https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47142142/equivalent-of-httpresponseexception-ihttpactionresponse-for-net-core-webapi-2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `HttpResponseException` in the core web api:

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ApiUser Post([FromBody] ApiUser model)
        {
            if (model.Email == "11")// this condition can be changed as your requirement.
            {
                var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                response.Content = new StringContent("Email already exists.");
                throw new HttpResponseException(response);
            }

            return new ApiUser();
        }
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

### Update

You can also change return type as `IActionResult` to return different content as follow:

```
   [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody] ApiUser model)
        {
            if (model.Email == "11")// this condition can be changed as your requirement.
            { 
                return BadRequest("Email already exists.");
            }

            return Ok(new ApiUser());
        }
```

The test result is the same as before.

Comment: It does seem I can still use "HttpResponseException" if I install a package called "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core", but this hasn't been updated since 2018.  I'm not sure this is the best solution.  Great video.  I just installed Postman to help me test this.

Comment: @ErnieThomason, if you don't want to use HttpResponseException, you can change your return type to `IActionResult `, as the method you update in your question, but there are some details to change ,I have updated in my post, you can follow it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  This gives me enough info on my options so I can move forward.