# How to return a BadRequest when the return type is not an ActionResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

It seems that the `HttpGet` method's return type need not be an `ActionResult`. For example, the following method works:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("list")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<MyItem>> List()
```

But then, how can I return a BadRequest (`BadRequest("...")`) in this case?

Comment: I usually use a middleware and custom exceptions. I create a BadRequestException class and throw it wherever necessary. In the middleware I check for the exception type and set the response status to 400

Comment: I think you can use ActionResult in your current method also and then return BadRequest. Like this

    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<MyItem>>> List()

Comment: @Arjunsinhjadeja I thought about that, but the return type looked too complicated. If that is the recommended way, I will do that.

Comment: what kind of conditions do you expect to return a bad request in the HttpGet method above?

Comment: HttpResponseException used to be the way to go in WebAPI, but it was removed in Core as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47142142/equivalent-of-httpresponseexception-ihttpactionresponse-for-net-core-webapi-2).

Comment: @DamnVegetables Ya of course that is the correct way. I have used that all the time.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to respond with `BadRequest` from within the controller method, you can use the following approach as recommended by Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-5.0#synchronous-action)

```
[HttpGet("list")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(IEnumerable<MyItem>))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public async IActionResult List()
{
  // Code to validate request
  if(requestIsValid)
  {
    // Code to get IEnumerable of MyItems
    return Ok(myItems);
  }
  else
  {
    return BadRequest()
  } 
}
```