# HTTP status code 200 but access denied. WebAPI ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am calling a Web API method like this:

```
   $.post("/api/attendances", { gigId: button.attr("data-gig-id") })
                    .done(function() {
                        button.removeAttr("btn-default")
                            .addClass("btn-primary")
                            .text("going");
                    })
                    .fail(function() {
                        alert("something went wrong");
                    });
```

And the Web API class looks like this:

```
 [Authorize]
public class AttendancesController : ApiController
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public AttendancesController()
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult SaveAttenance(AttendanceDto dto)
    {
        string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        if (_context.Attendances.Any(a => a.GigId == dto.GigId && a.AttendeeId == userId))
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _context.Attendances.Add(new Attendance()
        {
            GigId = dto.GigId, 
            AttendeeId = userId
        });


        _context.SaveChanges();


        return Ok();
    }


}
```

I am testing the call with anonymous user,when calling the method, I get status code 200 back which is not what I am expecting. I am also receiving this:

> responseText :"{"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this
>   request."}" 
>   status:200 
>   statusText : "OK"

Why isn't the Authorize attribute returning a status code that matches the responseText? In my case, the JavaScript code inside the .done function will execute regardless if the user is authorized or not. Any guidance is appreciated.

Update: Here's a link to my web.config if it helps: https://pastebin.com/B26QGjv8

Comment: Make sure you are not using `[System.Web.Mvc.Authorize]` instead use `[System.Web.Http.Authorize]` , also add `WebApiConfig` code so others may find it useful to guide you.

Comment: @stom Updated post to include web.config

Comment: I mean `WebApiConfig.cs` file, its under `App_Start` folder in your project.

Answer (score 0):

That's because Although you are using the [Authorize] attribute, You are not doing anything with the result.

The method works as expected, you are issuing a request, you are not authorized but you continue on with your work in the controller.

Handle your exception in the controller:

Override the On Exception method and create an exception attribute:

```
    public class NotImplExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute 
    {
        public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            if (context.Exception is NotImplementedException)
            {
                context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented);
            }
        }
    }
```

And in your controller call it like this:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    [NotImplExceptionFilter]
    public Contact GetContact(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("This method is not implemented");
    }
}
```

In your WebApiConfig.cs add:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Filters.Add(new ProductStore.NotImplExceptionFilterAttribute());

        // Other configuration code...
    }
}
```

Use This as reference, All snippets are taken from here:

[Handling exceptions in Web Api.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling)

Comment: If we use `[Authorize]` attribute, anonymous user will get Unauthorized `status code : 401` but OP is getting 200. Have you checked with sample WebApi Project ?

Comment: Yes and my answer is according, please note it. Notice as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205599/asp-net-web-api-correct-way-to-return-a-401-unauthorised-response