# How to return status code 401 along some additional data?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core

I am trying to write a custom Authorize attribute to authorize some of the API endpoints and MVC actions. Following this StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41348219/339725), I wrote a custom attribute. I am using UnauthorizedResult to return 401.

1. For Web API, How can I return status codes 401 or 403 along with
   some additional message as JSON payload?
2. For MVC Actions that return
   HTML, How can I return status codes 401 or 403 and redirect to different URL?
3. How can I check if the request is WebAPI or MVC
   action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your first question, this is how overridden method of authorization attribute may look like. Error message will be status message and content is in response body.

```
public override Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    string errorMessage = "User has no enough permissions to perform requested operation.";

    var httpContent = new StringContent("{ \"some\": \"json\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
    {
        ReasonPhrase = errorMessage,
        Content = httpContent
    };

    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

From MVC action you can return status code like this `return StatusCode(418);` or using dedicated method like `return Unauthorized();`. To redirect you can use [`RedirectToAction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx) or [`context.Response.Redirect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I found the suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205599/asp-net-web-api-correct-way-to-return-a-401-unauthorised-response easier.

Answer (score 1):

A more modern response that applies to `ASP.NET Core` at least would be

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CtrlAction()
{
    ...
    var result = // whatever object you want
    return StatusCode((int) HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, result);
}
```

Comment: This will set the content, not the ReasonPhrase, which is more applicable to extra exception info messages