# ASP.NET core JWT authentication always throwing 401 unauthorized

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt, asp.net-authorization

I'm trying to implement JWT authentication on my asp.net core webAPI as simply as possible.
I don't know what i'm missing but it's always returning 401 even with the ***proper*** bearer token.

here is my configureServices code

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            }).AddJwtBearer(
               x =>
               {
                   x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                   x.SaveToken = true;
                   x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                   {
                       ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                       IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("A_VERY_SECRET_SECURITY_KEY_FOR_JWT_AUTH")),
                       ValidateAudience = false,
                       ValidateIssuer = false,
                   };
               }
                );
            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddDbContext<dingdogdbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("dingdogdbContext")));
        }
```

and this is how I'm generating token

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("/Login")]
        public ActionResult<User> Login(AuthModel auth)
        {
            var user = new User();
            user.Email = auth.Email;
            user.Password = auth.Password;
            //var user = await _context.User.SingleOrDefaultAsync(u=> u.Email == auth.Email && u.Password==auth.Password);
            //if(user==null) return NotFound("User not found with this creds");

            //starting token generation...
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var seckey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("A_VERY_SECRET_SECURITY_KEY_FOR_JWT_AUTH"));
            var signingCreds = new SigningCredentials(seckey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);
            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Id.ToString()) }),
                SigningCredentials = signingCreds,
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
            });
            user.Token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
            return user;
        }
```

And I added app.useAuthorization() very after the app.useRouting().
when i'm sending POST request to /Login I'm getting the token. but when I'm using the token in for querying any other endpoint using postman(added the token in authorization/JWT in postman) getting 401 unauthorized every time.
is there anything I'm missing still?

Comment: How are you passing the token?
In your StartUp.Configure, are you using app.UseAuthentication()?

Comment: Oh thanks. I was just using app.UseAuthorization() and not app.UseAuthentication(). added that and it worked!

Answer (score 107):

Keep in mind that the `UseAuthentication`, `UseRouting` and `UseAuthorization` middleware must in correct in order for the ASP framework properly inject the identity context to http request.

It should look like this: (.NET Core 3.1)

Edit: the same code applies to .NET 5 & .NET 6

```
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
```

Comment: this should be marked as answer, since it suggests to add app.UseAuthentication() before UseAuthorization(): if the two instructions are in the wrong order, 401 will be issued!

Comment: Middleware order solved the issue for me as well on .NET Core 3.1. Thanks

Comment: Perfect, this is the solution

Comment: @DerekWilliams I'm not sure if it's good or bad :P

Comment: Not sure why .Net Core document suggest otherwise? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-5.0
It says specifically After UseRouting, and Before UseEndpoints

Comment: This is the ANSWER

Comment: Thank you so much! Been fighting this all afternoon and your solution sorted out the problem straight away!

Comment: why `UseRouting` set between them? I never saw such an order before

Comment: Frank honestly i had this issue and it does makes perfect sense to have them in this order, but it would took me hours to figure out what is the issue even thought it is trivial logic, thanks so much

Comment: For me ordering doesn't solve the problem, so it's not an answer.
.NET Core 3.1
```
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseCors(cors => cors.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors();

// Add authentication to the pipeline
app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();```

Comment: This answer solved my problem with repeated, inexplicable, 401 returns. I would like to add that useMvc() should be after useAuthentication() and before useRouting().

Comment: .NET 8 also did not solve my problem.  The order is as specified, although I do not have `.AddRouting()` nor `.UseEndpoints()`.  This is exactly my problem, see my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78070303/jwt-bearer-token-is-being-issued-but-endpoint-authentication-fails

Answer (score 28):

Step 1 :
First make sure the order of the **configure** method in the **stratup.cs** class :

below i have given the valid order form for asp.net core 3.1

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        
        app.UseAuthorization();
       

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

If Step one not working then try Step 2:
make sure  the token validation parameter and the token generation parameter & algorithm are same for that go to the ConfigureServices method of the startup.cs class and also go to the class or method where you have generated the token in my case it was UserService class

**ConfigureServices method code :**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("mySQLConnectionString");

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(connectionString));
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 5;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
        {
            auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            
        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = Configuration["AuthSettings:Audience"],
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["AuthSettings:Issuer"],
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                IssuerSigningKey =
                    new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["AuthSettings:key"])),
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

            };
        });
        services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
        services.AddControllers();
    }
```

**Token Generation code :**

```
 public async Task<UserManagerResponse> LoginUserAsync(LoginVIewModel model)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
        if(user == null)
        {
            return new UserManagerResponse
            {
                Message = "There is no user with that email",
                iSSuccess= false
            };
        }
        var result = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password);
        if(! result)
        {
            return new UserManagerResponse
            {
                Message = "Your Provided password not match eith our system ",
                iSSuccess = false
            };

        }

        var clims = new[]
        {
            new Claim("Email", model.Email),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id)
        };
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["AuthSettings:key"]));
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: _configuration["AuthSettings:Issuer"],
            audience: _configuration["AuthSettings:Audience"],
            claims: clims,
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(30),
            signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
            );
        string tokenAsString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

        return new UserManagerResponse
        {
            Message = tokenAsString,
            iSSuccess = true,
            ExpireDate = token.ValidTo
        };
    }
}
```

also please note that , In my case I have some spelling mistake in  appsetting.json
For example in the token generate code i have called the Audince but in the appSetting.json  it was Audience . thats why both Audience not match .

```
             audience: _configuration["AuthSettings:Audince"]
```

**Appsetting.json code :**

```html
"AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AuthSettings": {
    "key": "TThis is mfw sec test token",
    "Audience": "www.mfw.com",
    "Issuer": "www.mfw.com"
  }
```

Comment: Just give a upvote.  .  I have waste many days :(

Comment: thank you, the order inside Configure sure is crucial :)

Answer (score 5):

After struggling with this issue for hours, and trying different things from the multiple questions. Here is how I identified the problem:

Turn on the logging for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` package in your `appsettings.json` file

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Trace",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "Information"
      }
    }
  },
// other attributes
}
```

This will log the authentication failures to the Visual Studio server console.

[image]

In my case, I was not passing the expires parameter to the `new JwtSecurityToken` constructor while generating the token. But I was validating the token lifetime in the `TokenValidationParameters` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to check that the JWT token generated using your configureServices code is valid or not.To validate JWT token you can use [JWT debugger](https://jwt.io/). It will parse the JWT token value into each parameter by which you can verify that which of the parameter values assigned incorrectly and JWT debugger also  provide you JWT valid or invalid.
Once you figure this out you can work on identified errors or next course of action.

Answer (score 0):

There are some other issues here, that you may want to take a look at and potentially improve. The login mechanism currently contains a token that has a 7 days expiry. That means exposed tokens will still allow an attacker to access and impersonate the user for 7 days. In general it would be better to:

- Log the user in and generate a token which is only good for 1 hour
- Give the user a permanent device token to represent the device
- Validate the device and token (even when expired) and possibly generate a new token.

This gives the user the ability to "log out" of all sessions in case something is compromised. Specifically these sorts of functionality and more are available by most authentication providers such as [Auth0](https://auth0.com) or authorization providers such as [Authress](https://authress.io).

Answer (score 0):

### Recap

In my case I was not using any Identity Server Yet I was providing the Host as a ValidIssuer.
It validated the `Authority` for the algo and keys which returned nothing, this caused the system to throw an unhandled exception.
Solved this By Removing `options.Authority` from `JwtBearerOptions` in `AddJwtBearer(options => ...)`.

After that I faced the 401 ERROR, resolved it by removing `options.Audience` from `JwtBearerOptions` in `AddJwtBearer(options => ...)`, Also added `ValidateLifetime` to `TokenValidationParameters` (which you can see below in part 1)

---

### Code

PART (1) JWT Configuration

in .NET 6 :

```
builder.services.AddAuthentication(options => 
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options => 
 {
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() 
    {
       ValidateIssuerSigningKey = jwtSettings.ValidateIssuerSigningKey,
       IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSettings.IssuerSigningKey)),
       ValidateIssuer = jwtSettings.ValidateIssuer,
       ValidIssuer = jwtSettings.ValidIssuer,
       ValidateAudience = jwtSettings.ValidateAudience,
       ValidAudience = jwtSettings.ValidAudience,
       RequireExpirationTime = jwtSettings.RequireExpirationTime,
       ValidateLifetime = jwtSettings.RequireExpirationTime,
       ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
    };
});
```

---

### Extra

GET your JWT Settings from Appsettings using Either this
Where

> "JsonWebTokenKeys"

is the name of section in `configuration` :

```
var jwtSettings = new JwtSettings();
Configuration.Bind("JsonWebTokenKeys", jwtSettings);
builder.services.AddSingleton(jwtSettings);

//PART (1) => JWT Configuration goes here
//..
//..
```

OR this :

```
services.Configure<JwtSettings>(configuration.GetSection("JsonWebTokenKeys"));
using (ServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider())
{
   var jwtSettings = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<JwtSettings>>().Value;
   
   //PART (1) => JWT Configuration goes here
   //..
   //.. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue over and over again. I figured out that it was because the
`TokenValidationParameters` in `.AddJwtBearer()` have to be like:

```
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
    };
```

Only in that case I had it working.

Answer (score 0):

*In case it might be helpful for some.*

Make sure you are adding "**Bearer**" before the authentication token. In Swagger input field, I was putting only the token without "Bearer" text, raising same error.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem and could not find the solution until the end of day, so I closed the visual studio and shutdown the system. When I started the system next day the authentication started working in postman `MAGICALLY` without making any changes. So if you are stuck, give this a try.