# Returning an Unauthorized ViewResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I've replaced an `[Authorize Attribute]` on a Controller's function with code inside the function and would like to try and return the same result as the attribute would, is this possible or would I have to make further changes?

I'm trying to return an `Http 401 Unauthorized` from a function which returns of type ViewResult.

I've already tried return Unauthorized but this will not work as I am returning of type ViewResult.

```
public ViewResult Function([FromQuery] int? Id)
{
   if (!User.HasRole("GenericRole"))
   {
     return _____;
   }
}
```

Apologies if I have not provided enough information to formulate an answer

Comment: Depending on the version of MVC/WebAPI, maybe this?:  `return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();`  Note that would be an `ActionResult`, not a `ViewResult`.

Comment: I am assuming you are using old asp.net mvc from looking at your return type `ViewResult`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Web API : Correct way to return a 401/unauthorised response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205599/asp-net-web-api-correct-way-to-return-a-401-unauthorised-response)

Comment: I've tried "return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();" But am given a "the type or namespace name could not be found"-error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return

```
return Unauthorized();
```

or you can throw exception

```
throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
```

Comment: I ended up using your first solution and switched to return type Actionresult

Answer (score 0):

If you want this View to be available for any user who has a specific role then then this is how you should do it.

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public ViewResult Function([FromQuery] int? Id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Or otherwise if you want to show this view for all roles except one then do this way.

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Function([FromQuery] int? Id)
    {
        if (!User.HasRole("GenericRole"))
            return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();

        return View();
    }
```