# How do I make an ASP.NET Web API controller method which can return either a result or Unauthorized?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have this controller method:

```
public IEnumerable<GetPersonListResult> Get()
{
    var systemID = Authenticator.AuthenticateUser(Request);
    if (systemID == 0)
        return Unauthorized();
    var dc = DataContextFactory.GeneralDataContext(ConnectionStrings.GetSystemConnectionString(systemID));
    return dc.GetPersonList(null, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

But I get a compile error on the `return Unauthorized();` line because the result of that call cannot be converted to `IEnumerable<GetPersonListResult>`. How can I alter this method so it can return either the data in question or the result of `Unauthorized()`?

Comment: Don't do the auth inside the function, learn how to use authorisation attributes. Otherwise you will have to copy this code everywhere, and throw exceptions (e.g. `throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Web API : Correct way to return a 401/unauthorised response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205599/asp-net-web-api-correct-way-to-return-a-401-unauthorised-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to return a type `IHttpActionResult` (such as `Unauthorized()`) then instead of returning `dc.GetPersonList` at the end of your method... you're going to want to `return Ok()` and pass in `dc.GetPersonList()` as an argument.

Refactor into:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    var systemID = Authenticator.AuthenticateUser(Request);
    if (systemID == 0)
        return Unauthorized();
    var dc = DataContextFactory.GeneralDataContext(ConnectionStrings.GetSystemConnectionString(systemID));
    return this.Ok(dc.GetPersonList(null, null, null, null, null, null));
}
```

For further information see [the MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results#ihttpactionresult)