# Extract custom message from 401 Unauthorized response

Tags: c#, exception

How do I extract my custom message from the API 401 response?

I return Unauthorized in the API:

```
return Unauthorized("my custom message");
```

In my client winform app I want to show my custom message, but the message I get from the API is "Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)."

Is it possible to extract my message?

Comment: did you see this is post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205599/asp-net-web-api-correct-way-to-return-a-401-unauthorised-response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did -

```
var response = httpClient.PostAsync(url, hc).Result;
string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
  throw new Exception(response.StatusCode + " - " + responseBody);
}
```

Now I get my custom error from the API.

Answer (score 0):

Using something like this example: [HttpResponseMessage Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage?view=net-7.0)

```
// HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use. See Remarks.
static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

static async Task Main()
{
    // Call asynchronous network methods in a try/catch block to handle exceptions.
    try
    {
        using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.contoso.com/");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        // Above three lines can be replaced with new helper method below
        // string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);

        Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
        Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
    }
}
```

Yoou can extract your message from the response body:

```
// Extract your message from the response body
string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: the line response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); throws the exception again. What I did is to check the status code. Thanks